# Azure Data Studio Uses Single Quotes for JSON

Tags: azure-data-studio

I can't find a setting in Azure Data Studio, if there is one, that will display JSON results with double quotes rather than singles.

Example:

```
'EarliestStartDate': '2020-01-04T00:00:00'
```

A little bit of extra effort is needed when copying and pasting into n++/vs code and I have to switch the singles to doubles in order to "quickly" format it.